# Why do I get UnauthorizedAccessException for a file I just created?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a piece of code that looks something like:

```
File.Copy(fileInfo.FullName, newPath, true);
...
File.SetAttributes(fullServerPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(fullServerPath);
```

That works just fine for all except one mp4 file as of the moment. When trying to do that with the mp4 file I get a `UnauthorizedAccessException` and I can't figure out why. As I said, it works for all other file types like pdf, doc, ...

Why do I get `UnauthorizedAccessException` if I (or the user running the program) am the creator of the file when I try to delete it?

**UPDATE:** I'm using TikaOnDotNet and it seems like it is when I do the `Extract` this happens for one file type.

It isn't in use by another process as far as I can tell. Before delete I tried to open it using `fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);` where I say I don't want to share it with no one. And that works fine as well. This is very weird.

Comment: Creation and Deletion of files are different privileges. Maybe your user only has one of them in the path he is doing this in?

Comment: The File system is async, it might still be writing the File. Other processes can be notified. So maybe your MediaPlayer app is reading (or even normalizing/converting) your mp4.

Comment: @nvoigt, as I said in the question. I am allowed to do exactly the same thing with other files so I do have the right access rights.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, what in my piece of code is async you mean? The `Copy` method is synchronous as far as I know.

Comment: Of course it looks synced. But between you and the rest of the world, you can't even lock anything.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, but do I get a `UnauthorizedAccessException` if it is in used? Also, there is no other program that opens the file. The scenario is that I copy the file from a network share to local disk because I'm using a third party library to extract data from the file which only works with local files, and when I'm done with the extraction I delete the file. So no other program will use the file.

Comment: Is there a significant difference in size between this video file and the other files you've tested with? Could it be that copying is not completed, or something like that, when you attempt to delete it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, btw. I really like your comments :).

Comment: @Kjartan, this file is a little bit bigger than the other files. But isn't `Copy` synchronous? If it is it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Can handle.exe help you monitor what's going on and see if any external process is locking it? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: I think I've found the part causing the problem now, I'm using TikaOnDotNet to extract the data, and metadata, of a file but it seems like it can't handle mp4 files. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: @Yngvar, I just process explorer instead and it says that for my mp4 file it is the actual program that holds a reference to the file, but for other files it don't. Is there a way to force the "connection" to the file to close?

Comment: I believe you can force a file handle close, for instance by using handle.exe, see http://superuser.com/questions/486668/how-to-unlock-files-using-handle-exe-and-process-name. 

But be careful, the handle might be reused causing corruption on other files http://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows/15695#15695